# Iterating through a PHP array and extracting values

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I'm trying to create a menu page that is divided by menu type (div_id) and item type (grp_id), and displays the item info: title, description, price, etc.  Something like the following, though each grp_id should be in it's own html table (e.g. "Beer - bottled" all items listed in one table, "Beer - draft" in another). Also, each menu (e.g. Beverages, Salads, etc.) should be in a separate accordion window:

### Beverages

***Beer - bottled***

Killian's : $4.75
Molson : $4.75
Peroni : $6.00

***Beer - draft***

Guiness : $5.50

***Wine - red***

Banfi, "Colle di Sasso", Italy : $15.75
Bell'agio, Chianti, Italy : $16.95

***Wine - white***

Beringer, Moscato, Califormia : $14.95
Placido, Pinot Grigio, Italy : $14.95

### Salads

Antipasto Salad : $6.25
Grilled Chicken Salad : $7.95
Mesclun Side Salad : $4.95

And so on...

### The data is in a MYSQL table:

Column  Type    Null    Default

menu_id int(10)     No
div_id  int(10)     No
grp_id  int(10)     Yes     NULL
cat_id  int(10)     Yes     NULL
date_b  date    No
date_e  date    No
price   float(6,2)  Yes     NULL
price2  float(6,2)  Yes     NULL
price3  float(6,2)  Yes     NULL
title   varchar(255)    No
descr   text    Yes     NULL
special enum('n', 'y')  No      n
ordr    int(4)  No      10

div_id, grp_id, and cat_id are foreign keys whose tables contain the menu type (div_id)(div_name) and item type (grp_id)(grp_name).

### In trying to do accomplish this I have queried the DB like this:

```
$query_listMenu = sprintf("SELECT menu.menu_id, menu.div_id, m_div.div_name, menu.grp_id, m_grp.grp_name, menu.cat_id, m_cat.cat_name, m_cat.cat_ord, menu.title, menu.descr, menu.price, menu.price2, menu.price3, menu.date_b, menu.date_e
FROM menu
LEFT JOIN m_div ON ( menu.div_id = m_div.div_id )
LEFT JOIN m_grp ON ( menu.grp_id = m_grp.grp_id )
LEFT JOIN m_cat ON ( menu.cat_id = m_cat.cat_id )
WHERE menu.date_e >= NOW() 
ORDER BY m_div.div_name, ordr, m_grp.grp_name, menu.title");
```

dumping the results into a multidimensional array `$menuRows`

```
$listMenu = mysql_query($query_listMenu, $siteuser);
while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array($listMenu, MYSQL_ASSOC) )
{
$menuRows[] = $row;
}
```

#### Here is the code I have used to iterate through the array and display the contents, but it's not working correctly:

```
foreach ($menuRows as $section => $type) {
echo "<h3>" . $type['div_name'] . "</h3>";
echo "<table>";
echo "<tr><th>" . $type['grp_name'] . "</th><th>&nbsp;</th><th>&nbsp;</th><th>&nbsp;</th></tr>";
foreach ($menuRows as $menu => $item) {
    if ($item['div_name'] == $type['div_name']) {
        echo "<tr><td><strong>" . $item['title'] . "</strong>" . $item['descr'] . "</td><td>" . $item['price'] . "</td><td>" . $item['price2'] . "</td><td>" . $item['price3'] . "</td></tr>"; 
}
} echo '</table>';
}
```

The problem is that each menu is repeated as many times as there are items within the category.  For example, Beverages has 8 items, so the Beverages section is repeated 8 times.  Every category entry repeats equal to the number of items in that category.  This clearly is the result of having the nested foreach functions, but I can't figure out the right code.

Also, the code shown does not filter based on grp_name, so **all** beverages are ending up in one html table, beer and wine.  Though Wine - red will have its own table, just like Beer - draft, all beverages will be repeated in each.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Show the code where it dumps it into $menuRows. You're iterating through $menuRows twice with the exact same data.

Comment: Yes, show us what's inside $menuRows. Your nested foreach looks suspicious

Comment: Make a var_dump($menuRows); after the fetch-loop and you will probably find the issue.

Comment: `The problem is that each menu is repeated as many times as there are items within the category`. That's exactly what it should do, since you are nesting a loop within a loop of the same array

Comment: Do you mean after the first foreach?  So then how do I extract all Beverages : Beer - bottled, then Beer - draft, then Wine - red, then Wine - white, etc. without nesting a loop within a loop? That's what I'm not getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to subsection your rows like that, you need to create the array how you want it, not just dump the data in. For instance, to get you started, this is how you would create an item:

```
while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array($listMenu, MYSQL_ASSOC) )
{
    $item = array('title'=>$row['title'],'descr'=>$row['descr'],'price'=>$row['price'],'price2'=>$row['price2'],'price3'=>$row['price3']);

    $menuRows[$row['div_name']][$row['grp_name']][] = $item;

}
```

Then inside that same while loop, you would assign that item to a group array, and then that to a menu array. Your array will eventually look like this:

```
$menuRows = array(
    'menu1'=>array(
        'group1'=>array($item1, $item2, $item3), 
        'group2'=>array($item4, $item5, $item6)
    ),
    'menu2'=>array(
        'group3'=>array($item7, $item8, $item9)
)
```

Once your array is built, you would use your foreach like this:

```
foreach($menuRows as $divname=>$grp){
  // echo out what you want... contains Beverages, Salads
  foreach($grp as $grpName=>$itemArr){
     // again, echo out the divs
     foreach($itemArr as $item{
       // and now you can echo out your items
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please help me to understand what you mean in the second section $menuArray.  Is 'menu1' assigned based on the value of "div_name", in fact is 'menu1' really just the value of "div_name"?

Comment: In your example, menu1 would be 'Beverages', group1 would be 'Beer - bottled', group2 would be 'Beer - draft', menu2 would be 'Salads', etc and so on.

Comment: Isn't that why I need a foreach to create a multidimensional array for each menu type and each group type? Right, but since groups or menus can be added at anytime, how can I construct this menuArray using an unknown number of menus or groups?

Comment: But what I don't understand is how to build the array given the data in the table.

Comment: I updated the array... hopefully it should be correct, my eyes were crossing with all of the columns and rows.

Comment: I'm sorry I still don't understand, some of this syntax is new to me, particularly: 
    $menuRows[$row['div_name']][$row['grp_name']][] = $item;

Comment: I think I have it now. Let me play with it a bit and then I'll mark it answered.  Thanks so much for your help, I really didn't get this at all.

Comment: I can't thank you enough for your help. I'm still not sure I understand what you did, but it works perfectly. Thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome! Basically it takes the mysql results and creates an array just like the menu. Think of it as a file structure. The first array, div_name, is the first parent "folder", the second array, grp_name, is the sub "folder", and the items are what's in that sub folder.

Comment: If I understand correctly, [$row['div_name']] and ['$row['grp_name']] are references to the keys of $item within $menuRows?

Comment: Right, those are the columns returned from your mysql query.

Comment: So couldn't I just have created $item like this:    
    $item=array('div_name'=>$row['div_name'],'grp_name'=>$row['grp_name'],'title'=>$row['title'],'descr'=>$row['descr'],'price'=>$row['price'],'price2'=>$row['price2'],'price3'=>$row['price3']);

Comment: Yes, but you wouldn't have been able to output the menu in the correct order without a lot of sorting and checking. With the tiered array structure, you're able to use foreach easily to create a properly tiered menu.

Comment: Thank you for that, I finally understand what is going on in the code you wrote. Once I viewed <pre>print_r($menuRows)</pre>, I saw what you meant. What a great learning experience.